# How can I pass in the login/register data for my django-rest api in the form of a url?

Tags: django, api, url, django-rest-framework

I am following along with a book on the django-rest framework and I am having issues grasping a certain concept. The book uses the built-in Browsable API feature to do basic CRUD and LOGIN/LOGOUT/REGISTRATION functionality. What it fails to mention is how I can achieve such functionality using only the URL, which would be needed for, say connecting the API to the frontend of a REACT app.

**Example:**
I have an API which displays Posts and this path shows all posts:

```
path('api/v1/', include('posts.urls')),
```

I want to use this path for example, to register.

```
path('dj-rest-auth/registration/', include('dj_rest_auth.registration.urls')),
```

How would the URL look like ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use API documentation tools, such as swagger or redoc.

https://github.com/axnsan12/drf-yasg